# How do I detect the corners of a low resolution shape?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a low resolution concave quadrilateral cursor. My goal is to find the point he points to. So I thought of finding 4 corners and getting the farthest corner from each other. usually works fine but doesn't always detect corners accurately. Using blur gives little results, but I'm not sure it's enough. What would you suggest I do to improve my results?

```
cursor = cv.bitwise_and(captureHSV, captureHSV, mask=mask)

#resizeCurs = cv.resize(cursor, (0, 0), fx=0.60, fy=0.60)
#blurCurs = blur = cv.blur(cursor, (3,3))
grayCurs = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(grayCurs, 4, 0.01, 1)
corners = np.int0(corners)

coordList = []
for corner in corners:
    x, y = corner.ravel()
    cv.circle(cursor, (x, y), 1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    coordList.append([x, y])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: try to use ```cv2.threshold``` after little ```cv2.blur``` I think it's enough for this and then try to find corners here

Comment: do you know that it is a cursor of that shape? with findConotours and convexityDefect you should be able to get the 2+1 corners of the concave region.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I want to find the point where the quadrilateral is pointing so convexityDefect is not working for me. Using threshold increases false results for me. 
For now, using only blur gives the best results, but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

After detecting the canny edges of your image, converted to grayscale & blurred beforehand of course, you can dilate and erode the edges to get rid of noisy bumps and fill in little gaps.

But that wouldn't be enough to smooth out the results to 4 points, you'll need to use the `cv2.approxPolyDP` method to approximate the resulting contours.

Here is how it might go:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (7, 7), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 50, 50)
    kernel = np.ones((0, 0))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=1)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_erode

def get_contours(img):
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 10:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, peri * 0.04, True)
            cv2.drawContours(img, approx, -1, (0, 0, 255), 8) 

img1 = cv2.imread("cursor1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("cursor2.png")

get_contours(img1)
get_contours(img2)

cv2.imshow("Image 1", img1)
cv2.imshow("Image 2", img2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Where the red dots are the parts that were drawn on by the program.